# Please explain the use of for_each function in this c++ code

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, dictionary, stl

I was going through techiedelight article [link](https://www.techiedelight.com/check-given-key-exists-map-cpp/)

I didn't get the meaning of  `[&m](char &c) { m[c]++; }` in `std::for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), [&m](char &c) { m[c]++; });`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>
 
int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<char, int> m;
 
    std::string s("abcba");
    std::for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), [&m](char &c) { m[c]++; });
 
    char ch = 's';
 
    if (m.find(ch) != m.end()) {
        std::cout << "Key found";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Key not found";
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

Someone please explain how it is working.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each), [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), and [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[&m](char &c) { m[c]++; }
```

this is a lambda. A lambda is an anonymously typed function object using shorthand.

It is shorthand for roughly:

```
struct anonymous_unique_secret_type_name {
  std::unordered_map<char, int>& m;
  void operator()(char& c)const {
    m[c]++;
  }
};
std::for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), anonymous_unique_secret_type_name{m} );
```

the `[&m](char &c) { m[c]++; }` both creates the type and constructs an instance.  It captures (by reference) the variable `m`, which it exposes as `m` within its body.

As a function-like object (aka a function object), it has an `operator()` that can be called like a function.  Here this `operator()` takes a `char&` and returns `void`.

So `for_each` calls this function object on each element of the ranged passed (in this case, the string).

Comment: ...and does what to the map? Seems like you'd want that piece to fully explain the line.

Comment: @sweenish I assumed it was the lambda syntax that confused the OP.  I mean, I could also explain what `int main` means.

Comment: It's probably a good assumption, but they asked about the line of code. For completeness, I recommended finishing the explanation of the line. No need to condescend.